# How to transit at Frankfurt airport?

Tags: transit, fra

How do I transit at Frankfurt Airport? I will be flying from Gothenburg, Sweden, and transiting in Frankfurt before continuing to Hanoi, Vietnam. I need guidance on how to go from Terminal 1 to Terminal 2 in Frankfurt, including passing through security checks.

Comment: Just follow the signage... isn't it??

Comment: Yes, it’s just follow the signage. Should not be hard. If you actually need to transit from terminal 1 to 2, the sky train seems like the most likely option for you.

Comment: Don't worry, Frankfurt is Germany, its not as bad as transiting in the US. There are signs and in case of doubt people who speak (recognizable) English.  First of all you don't need to worry about your luggage, it will be forwarded automatically (check your baggage label). Just follow signs, don't get distracted by shops or restaurants until you reach your departure area.

Comment: AFAIK you don't need to go through another security check if you only transit from one terminal to the other. You are not "entering the country" in any legal sense.

Comment: @waka: Whether going from Sweden to Germany counts as entering the latter is not really a pertinent question (though in most contexts I would say it does) -- but the asker will need to pass through a passport check in Frankfurt, for leaving the Schengen area.

Answer (score 2):

My grandmother recently faced a similar issue so I've sent her a few videos of people transiting through FRA:

- [Transit walk at Frankfurt Airport, Terminal 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wHdRF8jlOq0)
- [Getting around Frankfurt Airport](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UOJjBwDapMg)
- [How to Connect at Frankfurt Airport](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jPEP_TMSIMg)

You can also study [a map of the airport](https://www.frankfurt-airport.com/en/airport-guide/orientation/airport-map.html) to get a better understanding of where you have to go.